# How do you get past the two big gears in Limbo?

Tags: limbo, xbox-360

I got to the Chapter of Limbo where there are the two big gears and the lever that reverses which direction they turn in. I am having a lot of trouble figuring it out from there.

Any tips?

Comment: don't forget to backtrack to get the achievement egg on the ledge right by that switch!

Comment: For the record, there are about a bazillion "big gears" in Limbo.   Next time include a screenshot perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Figured it out! It is a timing thing. The lever reverses the rotation direction of the gears, but there is a slight pause while the gears are switching directions where you can jump up on the one and then get to the other as it switches direction.